# Denied job, possibly since I am outside the country

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, human-resources, software-development, rejection

I am a software developer looking to change current jobs. I went through a round of many interviews (all online) with a company that is stateside, plus received positive feedback on all of the interviews. In my the last interview (the final round), I mentioned I was not currently stateside and outside the country due to the quaratine as the border was closed.

So it did not seem to cause an issue with anyone since they said the office is closed until next year, everyone was remote, (also the job is remote as well until then) and they asked if I will be back before the office opens up, and I said yes it will be no issue I will be back way before than (which is true as I should be back next month).

So after, talking to everyone had a sense everything went well, until this morning. Granted I did not receive the generic *"sorry we are moving on with other candidates" email.*
I did instead receive something that could be taken in the same way from HR, the reply I received from the HR receptionist, (the one handling all my interviews and so on, I thanked her for all the help she has given me). Her reply was *"Great that you have a interest in "COMPANY NAME" the team enjoyed speaking to you as well, please keep in touch with your current situation and when you expect to return to the states."* That was all.

- **So I wanted to ask what response (if any) should I respond with to this email?**
- **What was the red flag that I set off, by saying I was not stateside currently?**
- **Would you feel that the rejection email is on the way as well, or am I reading to much into this?**
- **Any tips to avoid this again?**

*Just wanted some general feedback as well, as it was a hit in my confidence, since I really wanted this job, as the company seemed great, definitely was a first choice type of place.*

Comment: Is this even a refusal or they put you on a potential list and would like to hear from you once you are fully back?

Comment: @Alrl I do not have a answer to that, since I have not received a rejection email, but I guess by HR saying "let us know when you are in the states" for that person to note this directly in the email, was a concern for them. So I would say a rejection email is/will follow shortly.

Comment: I think you are reading too much into this. I would just say "Thank you I will contact you as soon as I am back in the States". And then contact them once you are back. There are too many possibilities in this case. Maybe they have many positions, maybe they would like a follow up, maybe they chose someone else for that particular opening regardless of your position but they want to keep you on their short list, etc.

Comment: Do you have a US residence? There are legal implications to hiring somebody living in another country, and the company may not want to deal with it, particularly if they have not done so before.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes I do, I even explanied that I am still paying rent for a place, because all my stuff is there, plus my wife needs to go back ASAP as well.

Comment: @Alrl yes, that is what I am starting to think is the possibility here as well. Since I have not received a rejection email.... yet. Just wanted some feedback.

Comment: Even if you have a US residence, I believe there are tax implications for paying you to work in another country, sometimes even in other states within the US. If the company hasn't done this before or doesn't have any other employees in your current country, they may just not want to deal with it at this time.  Easier to wait until you are actually back.

Comment: @cdkMoose yeah I understand that, but its when a person has been abroad for over 8 months, and it`s usually the person that is not liable for taxes. I dont see the issue to be honest since I stated I would be returning in a month the only reason I am aborad is do to the quaratine, and I was planning to move where the company was located. As they asked me many times, if I would have a issue moving. Since the company is not located in my state as well. I figured it wouldnt matter where I am since its remote until next year.

Comment: Remote in country and remote out of the country are very different in this case.  The company has their own obligations separate from yours if they pay you to work in a country where they do not have a presence

Comment: @cdkMoose I guess, I mean I am still a citizen of the US, have a house and just paid taxes there in January as well. I think to not overlook situations caused by covid would be foolish. Again I have US bank accounts, so the pay would be of a non issue as well. I think there is more to this.

Comment: @PHPNoob, it's not a question of citizenship, it's a question of where you are physically working and where the company is based.

Comment: Could you explain why you're so sure that pay would be a non-issue?

Comment: @BSMP simple, I am a US citizen, I have residence in the US, along with the fact I return in two - three weeks. Again I was stuck in a quarantine, I didn't move or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should be honest about your physical location, your citizenship/immigration status, because there are legal and tax implications. A company may or may not be able to hire you depending on where you are and your legal status in the country where their offices are based at. However, I would advise that you only communicate these information with HR. They are the right people to make decisions with these information. You can tell other interviewers about it, but they might have unconscious bias towards you, which could go either way.

> So I wanted to ask what response (if any) should I respond with to
> this email?

When responding to this email, you should also be honest and open. Ask them all your questions with respect. Tell them you would like to know more about the situation, whether your physical location is a problem, how the company and you could work it out, or any other questions you might have. Also tell them how you feel about the company, the interviewers, and the job. If you show a strong interest and a positive attitude towards the job, the company and you might be able to work out a solution.

> What was the red flag that I set off, by saying I was not stateside
> currently?

As I mentioned earlier, there might be legal implications. Please note that people also have unconscious bias towards people live in different countries. But I don't feel it's fair to say *red flag* or something *you set off*. HR at each company should give you the best answer to these situations when it comes a specific job.

> Would you feel that the rejection email is on the way as well, or am I
> reading to much into this?

None of us knows the full context, so our speculation would be inaccurate. Why don't you ask the HR person openly? If they don't want you, you get a rejection that you will eventually get. You lose nothing.

> Any tips to avoid this again?

I'm not sure what you want to avoid. But from my standpoint, you would want to communicate to HR about your physical location and your citizenship status when you first talk to them about a job. If a company absolutely cannot hire you because of your situation, you will know before taking the interview. It would save you and the company some time.

But really, HR can be your friend before the compensation conversation or even during the compensation conversation. Their job is to find the company a suitable future employee as soon as possible, and HR can be desperate in some job market. Openly communicating to them who you are and what you need, you will likely save some time.

Comment: If OP is as dodgy and dismissive with HR as they are about their location in their post here...that's probably the red flag.

Comment: dodgy? didnt think disclosing my current location would matter much as I think by saying "not state side" pretty much summed it up, but if needed I am currently in Chile (do not understand how this would be such an important detail). Also how in my post was I "dodgy and dismissive" with HR?

Comment: @PHPNoob You're asking advice on how to avoid disclosing your current location to the next potential company.  Dodgy as hell.

Comment: @jack when did I ask for how to avoid disclosing my current location? Show me where I said that? Don't spam comments with in accurate info. As well I will be back in the states shortly it not like I moved, I was stuck in a quarantine.

Comment: @Jack When OP asked, "Any tips on how to avoid this", they meant the rejection that they're anticipating.